# What is the default visibility of a variable in solidity?

Tags: remix, solidity-0.8.x, smart-contract

```
mapping(uint256 => address) owner;
```

What is the default visibility of this variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If visibility is not specified then by default it is an 'internal' variable .
So , the owner mapping above is internal .

Comment: Is there a big difference between private and internal?

Comment: Hi @f22daniel , refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70019983/what-is-difference-between-internal-and-private-in-solidity

Answer (score 2):

it's internal, meaning that only functions from derived and internal contract can use it.